# 2 devices synced?

Tags: ipod-touch, apple-id

So my little sister did not know that you only can have one itunes account "running" on a computer. To cut the story short - her ipod is now "synced" with my apple-Id so when she downloades apps it's normal but when she has to update it's like she is logged into my account and it shows that she has to loggin with my password?? I was wondering if you perhaps could "Unsync" or somthing?

You could always restore her ipod, but then again it's boring..
I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score -1):

On her device, go to Settings > Store > tap on your ID > tap Sign Out.